# pick up a particular string before a hyphen and after a star in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, split

I want to pick up the three strings from a string for example `Vks - Vks * Son`

```
 txtName.Text = objDoctor.DocName.Substring(0, objDoctor.DocName.IndexOf("-")).Trim();
```

I have successfully obtained the first part i.e.

```
txtMidName.Text = objDoctor.DocName.Substring(1, objDoctor.DocName.IndexOf("-")).Trim();

 txtLastName.Text = objDoctor.DocName.Substring(0,objDoctor.DocName.LastIndexOf("*")).Trim();
```

Note: The second part is the MidName and 3rd part of `Vks - Vks * Son` i.e.  Son is the Last Name

Do check this out :

```
  Name = Name.Trim();

arrNames = Name.Split(' ', '-' , '*');

if (arrNames.Length > 0) {
    GivenName = arrNames[0];
}
if (arrNames.Length > 1) {
    FamilyName = arrNames[arrNames.Length - 1];
}
if (arrNames.Length > 2) {
    MiddleName = string.Join(" ", arrNames, 1, arrNames.Length - 2);
}
```

**Would really help someone**

Comment: Use the overload of [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) and pass the character position  from the last found char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
var parts = objDoctor.DocName.Split('-', '*');
txtName.Text = parts[0];
txtMidName.Text = parts[1];
txtLastName.Text = parts[2];
```

Please note that this will throw an exception if the string doesn't contain at least three parts.

Comment: Correct, it doesn't compile.

Comment: is there any way of counteracting the rest of the arrays being null??

Comment: @CJohnson: It does compile.

Comment: @vini: It depends on how you want to interpret the existing pieces, if there are less than 3...

Comment: i used the code as given in my edited question it worked well even if i did not have a middle name field

Answer (score 1):

Use the String.Split method. I'm also assuming you want to get rid of the spaces too?

```
String data = "Vks - Vks * Son";
String[] pieces = (from piece in data.Split(new char[]{'-', '*'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                select piece.Trim()).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(pieces[0]);
Console.WriteLine(pieces[1]);
Console.WriteLine(pieces[2]);
```

So I used a little LINQ to help trim the spaces off of the string pieces after they have been split.

This gives the following results on the command line:

```
Vks
Vks
Son
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Regular Expressions for parsing strings like these.

But of course there is a learning curve. But once mastered, it is so much easier. So here is the alternative:

```
string parse = "Vks - Vks * Son";
string pattern = @"(?'first'\w*)\s*-\s*(?'second'\w*)\s*\*\s*(?'last'\w*)";
Match m = Regex.Match(parse, pattern);
if (m.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["first"].Value);
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["second"].Value);
   Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["last"].Value);
}
```

Quick explanation of the pattern:

We are breaking the string in 3 parts: first, second, and last.

A word (0 or more characters) is \w* - if at least character is required use \w+

\s*-\s* is space (0 or more whitespace character) followed by '-' and then space (again 0 or more white space character.

\s*\*\s* - as '*' is a special character we have to escape it.

Hope this helps.

BD